VI search and replace for symbol with digits on either side
I have a large data set that has some values written in -1.00000e-00 notation and others written as -1.00000-00. I would like to replace all of the -00 notation with e-00. I cannot find/replace all of the + or - signs with e+ and e- as it would:

affect the values that are already in the proper notation
affect the sign of the negative numbers

I would like to search for a + or - with a digit on either side of it and replace the + with e+ and the - with e-.
I tried searching and replacing using :%s/\d-\d/e- but the digits on either side are wiped out.
Is there a way to search for a pattern, and only replace part of the pattern?

I'm guessing you're actually using Vim or some other modern implementation of Vi. I added the respective tag, feel free to rollback my change if I was mistaken.

You say "either side" but your pattern says "both sides". Which one is it?

@romainl very often in English "either side" has the same meaning as "both sides". eg: As I drove along the road, I saw houses on either side. (Or as in the question itself: the digits on either side)

It is incorrect, though. And we are talking regular expressions, here, where precision matters.

Use capture groups in the search and refer to them in the replacement.
The precise syntax will vary depending on what implementation of vi you are using but probably \(...\).
With nvi, for example:
:%s/\([0-9]\)\([+-][0-9]\)/\1e\2/g

In addition to \n to refer to the nth group (counting from the left), there is also & to refer to the entire match.

this in line substitution works with gvim also ?

@flash yes, afaik, this syntax is accepted by gvim

@flash gVim is the GUI version of Vim. NeoVim is a fork of Vim. The :substitute command works the same in either version. You can just type :help :substitute in your version of Vim to see what it can do for you.


Is there a way to search for a pattern, and only replace part of the pattern?

Yes, you can specify the start and end of the match using the \zs and \ze atoms, respectively.
Although I have to say this won't work in original Vi but in Vim and its forks. I assume you're actually using Vim, many Linux distributions provide an alias vi that points to vim. Either vi --version or the :version command will tell you.
Inserting \zs and \ze into your pattern it becomes:
:%s/\d\zs-\ze\d/e-/g

or, to substitute + and - in one go:
:%s/\d\zs[+-]\ze\d/e\0/g

Here, the \0 will be replaced by the whole matched pattern, that's either + or -.
I also added the g flag to match multiple times on one line. Otherwise, only the first match will be replaced.
For reference, see :help /\zs, :help \0 and :help :s_g.

I think you want to try using macros:
Macros are a way to do some action in Vi and be able to record it and repeat N times.
To start recording a macro you have to be in Normal mode.
Here is what you do (in NORMAL mode)

Type q, this will start recording a macro
Name your macro, say e for this example.
Now your macro is recording, you can run any series of commands, which in your example
it seems you want to go to the beginning of the line search for an e- or e+ and replace. Basically think about your replacement cases, and type them out like you would regularly.
When you are done recording, press q which will stop, now your macro is saved and you can invoke it by doing @{macro_name} or @e in this case.

Usually I just do gg and then do something like, 200@e in normal mode, to run my macro 200 times from the top. Remember though, if you are editing multiple lines you'll need to press enter to go to the new line, otherwise the macro will get stuck on the first line, it all depends on your use-case.
Try it out, I think it should do what you want.

I think this might be specific to the vim implementation of vi (which the OP may be using given that \d is also non-standard). However, the question is not tagged vim

more portable could be /[0-9][+-][0-9] RET ae ESC :map z n.z RET z :unmap z RET
